# Implementing soft delete

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, soft-delete

I have SQL Server 2014 and for college I want to implement soft delete on all my tables.

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy

CREATE TABLE Customers
(
    CustomerId int IDENTITY (1,1) not null,
    FirstName varchar (20) not null,
    LastName varchar (30) not null,
    Address1 varchar (30) not null,
    Address2 varchar (30) not null,
    Address3 varchar (30) null,
    Eircode varchar (8) null,
    DateOfBirth date not null,
    CountyId int not null,
    CountryId int not null,
    AssociationId int null,
    CustomerTypeId int not null,
    AccountId int not null
)
```

I want add a column for soft deletes using deleted at. What is the best way to do this?

Is it recommended that you use soft deletes (`deleted_at`) on all table on your database to keep it consistent.

Comment: Did you remember to declare foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Consistency is key.*

Whatever field name you use on one table try to keep it consistent for the other tables also, this will help greatly when you refactor code and need to apply a new where clause to many lines of code.

Using [`ALTER TABLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx) you could simply add a boolean field for `deleted` or you can log much more data such as the date/time and even the user. Again though, consistency is key. Whatever field names you use keep it consistent among the other tables.

Then you can create triggers to update the field information on delete, and also cancel the deletion from the trigger. Consistency in the field names will help you greatly here.

Answer (score 0):

Add field deleted_time (user etc. ) and add trigger to fill this fields on delete and cancel delete record. In query's add condition deleted_time is not null.
For better performance on current data you can create new table like "Customers_arch" and add trigger on delete to Customers, to insert row from Customers to Customers_arch with some additional fields like date_time, user etc, then you don't need change query's on your existing apps.

Answer (score 0):

Soft deletes add complexity to the data design and querying. Every query now has to remember to check `deleted_at`. Every join must also check `deleted_at`. This is something people are likely to forget.

If you don't need it, don't do it. Depending on what you're using this for, rolling backups, moving the records to a different table, or having an "active" join table is better design.

As an example of the latter, you'd have a join table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE active_customers (
    CustomerID INT REFERENCES Customers(CustomerId)
);
```

This might seem redundant, but it makes relationships simpler.  Now there is a clear way to determine who is active and who is not, query `active_customers` and join with `customers`. Triggers can be added to `active_customers` to update other tables when a customer is activated or deactivated. Relationships which require an active customer can be associated with `active_customers` and avoid having to qualify your joins.